# how to properly use comments-template.php

Tags: comments, comments-template

I want to modify comments form for both logged in users, and for those who are not.

I modified the form for those who are not logged in by changing my comments.php but I'm not quite sure how to modify my form for logged in users. I know I have to use comments_template(), but when ever I try to use it in my page.php, I get errors like this

```
Notice: Undefined variable: args in {PATH}/twwr-theme/comments-template.php on line 13
```

these are the contents of my comments.php, its a bit messy

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo "This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.";
    return;
}
?>
```

```
<h3><?php comments_number('No Comments', 'One Comment', 'Comments' );?></h3>

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
</div>

<ul class="commentlist">
    <?php //comment layout is in functions.php ?>
    <?php wp_list_comments('callback=comment_layout'); ?>
</ul>

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
</div>
```

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
    <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

 <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
    <p>Comments are closed.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

ID);
?>

Comment: The file is named `comments.php` usually. You can use another name, but that is not required. Add the code of your comment file to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your theme is built & we can't be 100% sure if this is right without seeing the code but most probably `comments_template` is the wrong function. Take a look at the `comment_form` function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

`comments_template` is the function generally used to include the comments file(basically to display the contents of `comments.php`, though this can be changed)

Again, it's possible for the theme to use `comments_template` for displaying the form & if the above doesn't work for you, please post the code